# How to set the length of an arraylist in js and save the changes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm here because I'm trying to set the length of an array to 0 but it doesn't save it.

Here is the list(I want to set the length of id_list to 0 and delete all element in it):

```
let constraints = [
        {
        id: 8, // id de la TTC
        name: "Covoiturage", // nom du type de TTC
        weight: 1, // poids de la TTC
        is_active: true, // contrainte active ?
        comment: "", // commentaire sur la TTC
        last_modification: null, // date de création
        weeks : [{nb: 14 , year: 2021},{nb: 33 , year: 2021}], // week a la forme : {nb: int , year: int}
        parameters : [
            {
            name: "Prof", // nom du paramètre dans la TTC
            type: 'people.Tutor', // nom du type des objets dans ce paramètre
            required: true, // paramètre obligatoire ?
            all_except: true, // tous sauf ?
            multiple : true,
            id_list: [2,6], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            },
            {
            name: "bonjour", // nom du paramètre dans la TTC
            type: 'people.Tutor', // nom du type des objets dans ce paramètre
            required: false, // paramètre obligatoire ?
            all_except: true, // tous sauf ?
            multiple : true,
            id_list: [1,8,5,6,7,8,9], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            },
            {
            name: "Module", // nom du paramètre dans la TTC
            type: 'base.Module', // nom du type des objets dans ce paramètre
            required: true, // paramètre obligatoire ?
            all_except: true, // tous sauf ?
            multiple : true,
            id_list: [1,2,3], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: [1,2,3,4] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 9, // id de la TTC
        name: "Random", // nom du type de TTC
        weight: 2, // poids de la TTC
        is_active: false, // contrainte active ?
        comment: "", // commentaire sur la TTC
        last_modification: null, // date de création
        weeks : [{nb: 14 , year: 2021},{nb: 33 , year: 2021}], // week a la forme : {nb: int , year: int}
        parameters : [
            {
            name: "Lettre", // nom du paramètre dans la TTC
            type: "people.Tutor", // nom du type des objets dans ce paramètre
            required: true, // paramètre obligatoire ?
            all_except: true, // tous sauf ?
            multiple : false,
            id_list: ["A"], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: ["A","B"] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            },
            {
            name: "Nombres", // nom du paramètre dans la TTC
            type: 'people.Tutor', // nom du type des objets dans ce paramètre
            required: false, // paramètre obligatoire ?
            all_except: true, // tous sauf ?
            multiple : true,
            id_list: [5], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: [1,5,6,8,9] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 10, // id de la TTC
        name: "Bonsoir", // nom du type de TTC
        weight: 8, // poids de la TTC
        is_active: true, // contrainte active ?
        comment: "", // commentaire sur la TTC
        last_modification: null, // date de création
        weeks : [{nb: 14 , year: 2021},{nb: 33 , year: 2021}], // week a la forme : {nb: int , year: int}
        parameters : [
            {
            name: "Lettre", // nom du paramètre dans la TTC
            type: "people.Tutor", // nom du type des objets dans ce paramètre
            required: true, // paramètre obligatoire ?
            all_except: true, // tous sauf ?
            multiple : false,
            id_list: ["A"], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: ["A","B"] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            },
            {
            name: "Nombres", // nom du paramètre dans la TTC
            type: 'people.Tutor', // nom du type des objets dans ce paramètre
            required: false, // paramètre obligatoire ?
            all_except: true, // tous sauf ?
            multiple : true,
            id_list: [1], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: [1,7,6,8,9] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            }
        ]
    }];
```

I use a button which is in a loop to set the length to 0, here is the button:

```
for (let l = 0; l < constraints.length; l++) {
  for (let k = 0; k < constraints[l].parameters.length; k++) {

 let btn_Suppr = document.createElement('input');
        btn_Suppr.setAttribute('type', 'image');
        btn_Suppr.setAttribute('id', 'image_Delete');
        btn_Suppr.setAttribute('src', '/static/base/img/suppression.png');
        btn_Suppr.addEventListener('click', () => suppr(constraints[l].parameters[k].id_list));
        btn_Suppr.setAttribute('width', '15px');
        btn_Suppr.setAttribute('height', '15px');

case_param_required.appendChild(btn_Suppr);// case_param_required is an html div where i add my button

  }
}
```

and here is the function suppr():

```
function suppr(param){
            console.log(param);
            param.length=0;
            console.log(param);

    }
```

In the console I get this :

```
(3) [1, 2, 3]

    []
```

Comment: sorry what are you trying to do?

Comment: What are `l` and `k`, and where do you initialise them, and where/when do they get updated?

Comment: My question is what output you expect ?

Comment: I don't expect any output, i just want to set the array length to 0.

Comment: I use two for to go in a js file here it is : ``` for (let l = 0; l < constraints.length; l++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < constraints[l].parameters.length; k++) {
    }
}  ```

Comment: @WAWABC you are storing the property length, check my answer.

Comment: sorry alumno i don't understand your question

Comment: You are storing the property of length for this reason you see [] because with length 0 you haven't any value in array.

Comment: I store  my array here : ``` let constraints = [
        {
     
        parameters : [
            {
            id_list: [2,6], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            }```

Comment: Please edit your question and put the televant code there. There are multple issues here.

Comment: ok i edited it now, is it more clear ?

Comment: *"doesn't save it"*: where? In a database? I don't understand what the problem is. Is the output not what you expect?

Comment: the probleme is that the id_list in parameters in constraints doesn't change but in console it change. i want to set the lenght of id_list in parameters to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a basic example of what happens if you try set length property:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(arr.length); //3

arr.length = 0; 

console.log(arr); // [] length is 0, that means, no values here.

console.log(arr.length); //0

arr.length = 3;

console.log(arr); //length is 3 and has undefined values.

console.log(arr.length); //3
```

Now seeing your structure, a issue is try add a element with same id, i change the property to class, but that isn't the real issue, because click event works with that.

```js
function suppr(param){
    console.log(param);
    param.length=0;
    console.log(param);
}


let constraints = [
        {
        id: 8, // id de la TTC
        name: "Covoiturage", // nom du type de TTC
        weight: 1, // poids de la TTC
        is_active: true, // contrainte active ?
        comment: "", // commentaire sur la TTC
        last_modification: null, // date de création
        weeks : [{nb: 14 , year: 2021},{nb: 33 , year: 2021}], // week a la forme : {nb: int , year: int}
        parameters : [
            {
            name: "Prof", // nom du paramètre dans la TTC
            type: 'people.Tutor', // nom du type des objets dans ce paramètre
            required: true, // paramètre obligatoire ?
            all_except: true, // tous sauf ?
            multiple : true,
            id_list: [2,6], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            },
            {
            name: "bonjour", // nom du paramètre dans la TTC
            type: 'people.Tutor', // nom du type des objets dans ce paramètre
            required: false, // paramètre obligatoire ?
            all_except: true, // tous sauf ?
            multiple : true,
            id_list: [1,8,5,6,7,8,9], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            },
            {
            name: "Module", // nom du paramètre dans la TTC
            type: 'base.Module', // nom du type des objets dans ce paramètre
            required: true, // paramètre obligatoire ?
            all_except: true, // tous sauf ?
            multiple : true,
            id_list: [1,2,3], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: [1,2,3,4] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 9, // id de la TTC
        name: "Random", // nom du type de TTC
        weight: 2, // poids de la TTC
        is_active: false, // contrainte active ?
        comment: "", // commentaire sur la TTC
        last_modification: null, // date de création
        weeks : [{nb: 14 , year: 2021},{nb: 33 , year: 2021}], // week a la forme : {nb: int , year: int}
        parameters : [
            {
            name: "Lettre", // nom du paramètre dans la TTC
            type: "people.Tutor", // nom du type des objets dans ce paramètre
            required: true, // paramètre obligatoire ?
            all_except: true, // tous sauf ?
            multiple : false,
            id_list: ["A"], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: ["A","B"] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            },
            {
            name: "Nombres", // nom du paramètre dans la TTC
            type: 'people.Tutor', // nom du type des objets dans ce paramètre
            required: false, // paramètre obligatoire ?
            all_except: true, // tous sauf ?
            multiple : true,
            id_list: [5], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: [1,5,6,8,9] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 10, // id de la TTC
        name: "Bonsoir", // nom du type de TTC
        weight: 8, // poids de la TTC
        is_active: true, // contrainte active ?
        comment: "", // commentaire sur la TTC
        last_modification: null, // date de création
        weeks : [{nb: 14 , year: 2021},{nb: 33 , year: 2021}], // week a la forme : {nb: int , year: int}
        parameters : [
            {
            name: "Lettre", // nom du paramètre dans la TTC
            type: "people.Tutor", // nom du type des objets dans ce paramètre
            required: true, // paramètre obligatoire ?
            all_except: true, // tous sauf ?
            multiple : false,
            id_list: ["A"], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: ["A","B"] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            },
            {
            name: "Nombres", // nom du paramètre dans la TTC
            type: 'people.Tutor', // nom du type des objets dans ce paramètre
            required: false, // paramètre obligatoire ?
            all_except: true, // tous sauf ?
            multiple : true,
            id_list: [1], // ids des objets pour le paramètre dans la TTC
            acceptable: [1,7,6,8,9] // ids des objets acceptables comme valeur du paramètre
            }
        ]
    }];


/*constraints[0].parameters[0].id_list.length = 0;

console.log(constraints[0].parameters[0].id_list);*/
let case_param_required = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

for (let l = 0; l < constraints.length; l++) {
  for (let k = 0; k < constraints[l].parameters.length; k++) {

 let btn_Suppr = document.createElement('input');
        btn_Suppr.setAttribute('type', 'image');
        btn_Suppr.setAttribute('class', 'image_Delete'); //Can't have the same id, i replace it to class.
        btn_Suppr.setAttribute('src', '/static/base/img/suppression.png');
        btn_Suppr.addEventListener('click', () => suppr(constraints[l].parameters[k].id_list));
        btn_Suppr.setAttribute('width', '15px');
        btn_Suppr.setAttribute('height', '15px');

        case_param_required.appendChild(btn_Suppr);// case_param_required is an html div where i add my button

  }
}
```

An example:

This is how is the constraint `id_list` value of the first button without remove data:

[image: Any data removed.]

Now i will click to the first button:

[image: Output when clicking]

Now i will check in `constraints[0].parameters[0].id_list`:

[image]

Comment: oh ok but why it's undefined values here in the second array ?

Comment: Because when you put length 0, its like remove the values from array, are forgotten by garbage collector i guess.

Comment: i don't understand why i doesn't delete all the values in my id_list[], like when i just do constraints[0].parameters[2].id_list.length = 0 it work, im lost.

Comment: In your example, what value has ``l`` and ``k`` when you call ``setAttribute`` ?

Comment: it's in a for so it can be l=0 and k=0 then l=0 and k=1 etc...

Comment: the second code  is exatly what i want but i when i click on a button

Comment: Put entire **constraints** structure, and the **loop** too.

Comment: Fixed, an issue was because you was trying to add the same id element, but this isn't the reason of no click event, all works fine. The ``case_param_required`` is different than yours, change it like you have it in your script.

Comment: Ok i see another constraints more bigger (you make an edit), i will check if works.

Comment: Ok it works too. Remember put this answer like a correct answer.

Comment: There is still a problem, it don't change it in constraints.parameters.id_list, the array is not empty after clicking on the button, it just change it in console.log but not in the constraints

Comment: It does i check in console, now i will put an example.

Comment: Ok thanks, after it finished i will put your answer as correct

Comment: Finished! You can check the screenshots.

Comment: Bro you are the best omg, I understand now, but why when i refresh the page it doesn't save changes applied to constraints ?

Comment: Like is there a way to save the changes so when i refresh it save what i've done ?

Comment: Thats because the variables aren't stored after refresh, a nice way is using localStorage. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage this will be stored after refresh, but you will need convert your array to string, because localStorage can store only strings.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo buena suerte para el examen